# how to turn off excessive buffering when running modelsim interactively with -c flag?

Tags: verilog, modelsim

how to turn off excessive buffering of the console print's when running modelsim with -c flag?  Example:

```
C:\> vsim -c
VSIM> source run.do
```

run.do is just a modelsim script to compile the design and run it 10 milliseconds.  The problem occurs when it hits the vsim command in the script, all the output is buffered until i hit Ctrl-C or I wait for a few minutes for the simulation to complete without displaying $display's as they occur during simulation.   (Its good code synthesizable verilog.  doesn't have anything funny going on like asynchronous loop.)

Log output from verilog simulation doesn't show up until Ctrl-C is pressed.

Using Free light version of Modelsim distributed with Intel/Altera Quartus 17 and Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using batch mode to get output without buffering, but you can't have interactive at the same time.

```
vsim -batch -do run.do
```